# slide a div using if/else and addClass and removeClass on a button click

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click').click(function() {
        if (("#sidebar").length > 0) {
            $("body").addClass('menu-hidden');
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass('menu-hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

How to slide a div on a button click, using add and remove class methods and by if/else statements?

Comment: I couldn't understand your question need detail

Comment: simply use the toggleClass, no need of using if/else here. $("body").toggleClass("menu-hidden");

Comment: @ameenulla0007 but he needs to check `#sidebar`

Comment: Please use toggle instead! Much better in your case.

Comment: i was trying something different than toggleClass..can you plz tell me some other method other than this.

Comment: post your html as well for betterment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#click').click(function() {
            if (("#sidebar").length > 0) {
                $("body").addClass('menu-hidden');
            } else {
                $("body").removeClass('menu-hidden');
            }


             $('.div_class').animate({
              right: '200px' //here you can give div width too
          });
        });

    });
```

This [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Abs5H/6/) will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

This will do it in the order you asked:

```
$('#showHideLink').click(function(){

    if (!$("#categoryNav").is(":visible"))
        $('#showHideLink, #mainNav').addClass("catMenuOpen");

    $("#categoryNav").slideToggle(function() { 
        if (!$("#categoryNav").is(":visible"))
            $('#showHideLink, #mainNav').removeClass("catMenuOpen");
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Check it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/g40c4gmh/)